# Excel - VBA : If statement not working with "Set Range = .Range(...) "

Tags: vba, excel

I noticed that my VBA program isn't working anymore when I use a If statement to try to set different range of cells to my variable cityListRange. Basically, if the cell "A:20"'s content is "Metro Manila", I want to initialize cityListRange to the range G21:G37 (a list of cities in Metro Manila). If not, then it would be another list (G41:G43) (later in my code it's using a match method with cityListRange as a reference).

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2") 
With ws 
    If Range("A20").Value = "Metro Manila" Then
        Set cityListRange = .Range("G21:G37") 'list of cities to compare to (IN METRO MANILA)
    Else
        Set cityListRange = .Range("G41:G43") 'list of cities to compare to (IN PROVINCE)
    End If
End With
```

My whole program is working fine when I just initialize cityListRange to one and only one range, but when I add my if statement, it stops working and I get no results returned at the end of my program. 
Do you know if there are counter indications to using If statement in this case ? If so, what would be the best way to write it ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the current `With` scope?

Comment: It's my current worksheet : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2")
With ws [...] End With.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error may be due to the missing period before `Range` in the `If` line.

Comment: Remember the green tick mark to the left to help both the answering guy and future visitors.

Comment: Sure, just have to wait a few minutes before being able to check this answer. Have a good day!